# How to Implement flip effect to new activity

Tags: android

I have two activities A,B .When i Click a particular button in Activity A,Acivity B has to appear with Flip animation.And when i press particular button in Activity B activity a has to appear with Fllip Animation please let me know.

Comment: 360 degree rotation = 0 degree rotation ?

Comment: I have a feeling Android devices don't support the Flip animation natively so they don't look like they're biting off the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html) something what you were looking for??